# Limit of $\frac{\sin(n-x)}{x}$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$

Tags: limits

I have to calculate the following limit:

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin{(n-x)}}{x} $$

I am aware that the limit:

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} = 0 $$

What I can't figure is if the result for the secons limit applies also to the first limit (the one I want to calculate). I thought that by using the method:

$$ -1 \leq \sin(n-x) \leq 1 \Rightarrow -\frac{1}{x} \leq \frac{\sin(n-x)}{x} \leq \frac{1}{x} \ \text{as} \ x\rightarrow \infty  $$

And due to the fact  that:

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}-\frac{1}{x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{x} = 0 $$

then I can conclude that:

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sin(n-x)}{x} =0 $$

Is my thought correct or am I missing something ?

Comment: Yep, just squeeze it.

Comment: Your method looks perfectly fine. After all, this result is expected: $\sin(n-x)$ is just, for all intents and purposes, a shift in phase of the sine function.

Comment: It holds independent of $n$, right ? I mean since the value of $\sin(n-x)$ will always be in $[-1 \ 1]$, it doesn't matter what $n$ is.

Comment: It's better to use absolute values.  $$|\sin(n-x)|\le1\implies \left|\frac{\sin(n-x)}x\right|\le \frac1x$$for $x>0$.

Comment: Alternatively, expand sin(n-x) in sin x, cos n terms and then use limit theorems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you have is correct! Despite the fact that the 'oscillation' of sine is made 'worse' by the $n-x$, it is still bounded in absolute value by $1$ so that the same trick applies. As mentioned in the comments, it may be cleaner to bound using absolute values:
$$
0 \leq \left| \dfrac{\sin(n-x)}{x} \right| \leq \dfrac{1}{x}
$$
for all $x>0$. Then as $x \to \infty$, we have
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{x}= 0
$$
so that by Squeeze Theorem, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\sin(n-x)}{x}= 0$. In any case, well done!